# Passing Variables in C - Making a hangman game

Tags: c

Making a simple hangman game in C. I have experience in Java and I am having problems with the guessLetter Method. **I am trying to determine whether the character entered by the user is a character in the word.** Although if you see any other problems or have any advice for me, all is appreciated!!

```
    // Includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "hangman.h"

//Function Declarations
void getRandomWord(char* word);

// Global Variable Declarations
int wordLength = 0;



//Main Function
int main(void)
{
   char word[MAX_WORD_LEN + 1];
   unsigned wrongGuesses = 0;
   int guessedLetters[ALPHABET_SIZE] = {
      0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
   };





   srand( time(NULL));
   getRandomWord( word );
   displayWord( word, wordLength );
   guessLetter( word, guessedLetters);








   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


//Gets Random Word from Words Array
void getRandomWord(char* word)
{
   const char* words[NUM_WORDS] = {
      "array",      "auto",       "break",      "case",       "cast",
      "character",  "comment",    "compiler",   "constant",   "continue",
      "default",    "double",     "dynamic",    "else",       "enum",
      "expression", "extern",     "file",       "float",      "function",
      "goto",       "heap",       "identifier", "library",    "linker",
      "long",       "macro",      "operand",    "operator",   "pointer",
      "prototype",  "recursion",  "register",   "return",     "short",
      "signed",     "sizeof",     "stack",      "statement",  "static",
      "string",     "struct",     "switch",     "typedef",    "union",
      "unsigned",   "variable",   "void",       "volatile",   "while"
   };


    int randomNumber = rand() % NUM_WORDS;
    printf("Random Number is: %d\n", randomNumber);
    wordLength = strlen(words[randomNumber]);
    printf("Word Length is: %d\nWord is: %s\n", wordLength, words[randomNumber]);
    word = words[randomNumber];
    return word;



}


//Prints Word Formatted with dashes
void displayWord(char* word, int* guessedLetters)
{

    int x = 0;
    printf("%s \n", word);


    for (x = 0; x <= wordLength * 2; x++)
    {
        printf("=");
    }
    printf("\n|");

    for(x = 0; x < wordLength; x++)
    {

        if ( word[x] != guessedLetters )
        {



            printf("_|");
        }
        else
        {
            printf(guessedLetters);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

     for (x = 0; x <= wordLength * 2; x++)
    {
        printf("=");
    }


}


//User Makes Guess, Determines whether Guess is Correct or Incorrect
int guessLetter(char* word, int* guessedLetters)
{
    char firstGuess;
    int x;
    //puts(word); will print an @ and another strange symbol! This is where my problem is!

    printf("\nEnter Your Guess: ");
    scanf("%d\n", firstGuess);

    for(x = 0; x < wordLength; x++)
    {
        if( firstGuess == word[x])
        {
            printf("Correct Guess!!");
            return GOOD_GUESS;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Incorrect");
            return BAD_GUESS;
        }
    }

// Once a correct Guess is made that character will be added to the guessedLetters Array


}
```

Comment: No matter what the guess, Incorrect Guess is always printed as I have a feeling the word is not being correctly passed as when I try to print it, I get the @ sign. Noobie Quesiton I know!!

Comment: And the question is ? You should the edit question with that information rather then providing crucial part in comments.

Comment: Try cull. Hardest word to guess in hangman

Comment: Make sure you're compiling with stringent compiler warnings. If you're using GCC, I recommend `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` as a basic minimum. I usually don't run code that doesn't compile clean under those (along with the options such as `-std=c11 -O3 -g` to select the dialect of C). I use some extra options too — `-Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wold-style-declaration`, and sometimes `-Wshadow` and various others on occasion. These help me make sure I'm not making silly mistakes. (I still make mistakes, but they usually aren't ones the compiler can spot for me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many problems.

Less serious problem:

```
int guessedLetters[ALPHABET_SIZE] = {
   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
};
```

can be shortened to

```
int guessedLetters[ALPHABET_SIZE] = {0};
```

Serious problems:

- You use `word = words[randomNumber];`. This simply changes the local pointer `word` and makes it point to the string literal pointer to by `words[randomNumber]`. You probably need to copy each character by character. This can be done by using the `strcpy` function from `string.h`:

  ```
  strcpy(word, words[randomNumber]);
  ```
- You `return word;` from `getRandomWord` which is a function returning `void` (does not return anything). This is wrong. Remove `return word;`
- You call `displayWord( word, wordLength );` with second argument `wordLength` which is an `int`. But

  ```
  void displayWord(char* word, int* guessedLetters)
  ```

  expects an `int*` as its second parameter. Since `wordLength` is global, you don't have to pass it. `displayWord` cannot see `guessedLetters` as it is local in `main`. Pass it to `displayWord` instead of passing `wordLength`:

  ```
  displayWord( word, guessedLetters );
  ```
- Here `if ( word[x] != guessedLetters )` you compare a `char` with an `int*`. This makes no sense. It should probably be `if ( guessedLetters[x] == 0 )`
- You use `printf(guessedLetters);` and pass an `int*` as the first argument to `printf` which expects a `const char*` as its first argument. It should probably be `printf("%c", word[x]);`.
- `scanf("%d\n", firstGuess);` should be `scanf(" %c", &firstGuess);` for the reasons mentioned in [@SouravGhosh's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2173917/sourav-ghosh) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31238883/3049655).
- You return `GOOD_GUESS` and `BAD_GUESS` from `guessLetter`, but never use the return value. You need not return anything from this function. Just assign some value other than 0 to that position in `guessLetters`. So remove both the return statements and change

  ```
  int guessLetter(char* word, int* guessedLetters)
  ```

  to

  ```
  void guessLetter(char* word, int* guessedLetters)
  ```

  and

  ```
  if( firstGuess == word[x])
  {
      printf("Correct Guess!!");
      return GOOD_GUESS;
  }
  else
  {
      printf("Incorrect");
      return BAD_GUESS;
  }
  ```

  to

  ```
  if( firstGuess == word[x])
  {
      printf("Correct Guess!!");
      guessedLetters[x] = 1;     //Change the value of the current position
  }
  else
  {
      printf("Incorrect");
  }
  ```
- You declare just one function:

  ```
  void getRandomWord(char* word);
  ```

  what about the rest? Use:

  ```
  void getRandomWord(char* word);
  void displayWord(char* word, int* guessedLetters)
  void guessLetter(char* word, int* guessedLetters)
  ```

---

**Fixed code:** (untested):

```
// Includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "hangman.h"

//Function Declarations
void getRandomWord(char* word);
void displayWord(char* word, int* guessedLetters)
void guessLetter(char* word, int* guessedLetters)

// Global Variable Declarations
int wordLength = 0;

int main(void)
{
   char word[MAX_WORD_LEN + 1];
   unsigned wrongGuesses = 0;
   int guessedLetters[ALPHABET_SIZE] = {0};

   srand( time(NULL));

   getRandomWord( word );
   displayWord( word, guessedLetters );
   guessLetter( word, guessedLetters);

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


//Gets Random Word from Words Array
void getRandomWord(char* word)
{
    const char* words[NUM_WORDS] = {
       "array",      "auto",       "break",      "case",       "cast",
       "character",  "comment",    "compiler",   "constant",   "continue",
       "default",    "double",     "dynamic",    "else",       "enum",
       "expression", "extern",     "file",       "float",      "function",
       "goto",       "heap",       "identifier", "library",    "linker",
       "long",       "macro",      "operand",    "operator",   "pointer",
       "prototype",  "recursion",  "register",   "return",     "short",
       "signed",     "sizeof",     "stack",      "statement",  "static",
       "string",     "struct",     "switch",     "typedef",    "union",
       "unsigned",   "variable",   "void",       "volatile",   "while"
    };

    int randomNumber = rand() % NUM_WORDS;
    printf("Random Number is: %d\n", randomNumber);
    wordLength = strlen(words[randomNumber]);
    printf("Word Length is: %d\nWord is: %s\n", wordLength, words[randomNumber]);
    strcpy(word, words[randomNumber]);
}


//Prints Word Formatted with dashes
void displayWord(char* word, int* guessedLetters)
{

    int x = 0;
    //printf("%s \n", word); Why print it here? No need for this


    for (x = 0; x <= wordLength * 2; x++)
    {
        printf("=");
    }
    printf("\n|");

    for(x = 0; x < wordLength; x++)
    {

        if ( guessedLetters[x] == 0 )
        {
            printf("_|");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", word[x]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (x = 0; x <= wordLength * 2; x++)
    {
        printf("=");
    }
}


//User Makes Guess, Determines whether Guess is Correct or Incorrect
void guessLetter(char* word, int* guessedLetters)
{
    char firstGuess;
    int x;

    printf("\nEnter Your Guess: ");
    scanf(" %c", &firstGuess);

    for(x = 0; x < wordLength; x++)
    {
        if( firstGuess == word[x])
        {
            printf("Correct Guess!!");
            guessedLetters[x] = 1;     //Change the value of the current position
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Incorrect");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: made those changes thank you very much!

Comment: woops not all of them just the first two!

Comment: as for determining whether or not the user guessed letter exists in the word, how would I go about that? I have made the changes you suggested! Thank you !!

Comment: Should the guessed letter be added to the Array of Guessed Letters first before anything else? Then loop through the array?

Comment: @Luke Your program should work as expected after you do all the changes suggested in my answer. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Yep. completley forgot to declare my other functions wow, just reading through and understanding your other responses!! Thank you!!

Comment: @Luke Added fixed code. Hope it works as expected. And I assume that you've declared those constants in `hangman.h`.

Comment: Yes constants are declared in hangman.h, I do have to return GOOD_GUESS/BAD_GUESS though, So if I don't change them to void and add return statements after Correct/Incorrect Guess has been printed will that still run?

Comment: Also the random prints are there for testing purposes only, So I can see what's going on!

Comment: @Luke "_I do have to return GOOD_GUESS/BAD_GUESS though_" -- Are you required to? "_So if I don't change them to void and add return statements after Correct/Incorrect Guess has been printed will that still run?_" -- Yes, the program will run. But the output will be dashes (`_`) even when you guess a letter correctly. Since you do not use the return value from `main`, you do not need to return `GOOD_GUESS` and `BAD_GUESS`.  "_Also the random prints are there for testing purposes only, So I can see what's going on!_" -- I see. Ok.

Comment: Yeah, I am required to to return GOOD/BAD_GUESS in the guessLetter method. Is there any way I can fix that problem so that the guessed letters will also be printed? I appreciated your time so much!! Thank you!!

Comment: char firstGuess;
    int x;

    printf("\nEnter Your Guess: ");
    scanf(" %c", firstGuess);

Once %c was changed from %d, the compiler stops resonding. Leaving it as %d will cause correct guesses to print Incorrect Guess. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I run into the same problem when using 'gets' instead of 'scanf'

Comment: @Luke "_I am required to to return GOOD/BAD_GUESS in the guessLetter method. Is there any way I can fix that problem so that the guessed letters will also be printed?_" -- That would be a waste. If you insist, just add `guessedLetters[x] = 1;` before returning `GOOD_GUESS`. "_the compiler stops resonding_" -- You mean the "program", not "compiler". And I'll have to see your code if that's the case. Could you show me the updated code? "_I run into the same problem when using 'gets' instead of 'scanf'_" -- Never use `gets`. It is dangerous....

Comment: `int guessLetter(char* word, int* guessedLetters)
{
    char firstGuess;
    int x;
    

    printf("\nEnter Your Guess: ");
    scanf("%c", firstGuess);

    for(x = 0; x < wordLength; x++)
    {
        if(firstGuess == word[x])
        {
            printf("Correct Guess!!");
            guessedLetters[x] = 1;
            return GOOD_GUESS;

        }
        else
        {
            printf("Incorrect");
            return BAD_GUESS;

        }
    }
`

Comment: @Luke My bad... You need to use `scanf(" %c", &firstGuess);` instead of `scanf("%c", firstGuess);`. Note the ampersand(`&`) and the space before `%c`.

Comment: `int guessLetter(char* word, int* guessedLetters)
{
    char firstGuess;
    int x;
    

    printf("\nEnter Your Guess: ");
    scanf("%c", firstGuess);

    for(x = 0; x < wordLength; x++)
    {
        if(firstGuess == word[x])
        {
            printf("Correct Guess!!");
            guessedLetters[x] = 1;
            return GOOD_GUESS;

        }
        else
        {
            printf("Incorrect");
            return BAD_GUESS;

        }
    }
`

Comment: ahh trying to use the `code` but failing. Can you decipher that?

Comment: @Luke Display as code by surrounding it with bacticks (\`). And why are you posting the same comment several times? You can also edit your comment (within the first 5 minutes) to add more information instead of posting another comment.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, at first look,

```
scanf("%d\n", firstGuess);
```

is wrong. You're using wrong conversion specifier. It should actually be

```
scanf(" %c", &firstGuess);   //notice ALL the chnages
```

- Point 1: You need to use `%c` to read a `char`.
- Point 2: Your input should *exactly* match the supplied format string. I believe, you do not need to have a `\n` in the format string.
- Point 3: `%c` format specifier expects the corresponding argument to be a **pointer** to a `char` (as field width defaults to `1`)
- Point 4: Note the space  before `%c`, it helps to *eat up* any possible whitespace before the *expected* non-whitespace character input.

Comment: Woops, Just been playing with the code and forgot to change that back! Can %c and %d not be used interchangeably?

Comment: @Luke Nope, using wrong format specifier leads to  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: I suggest adding _Point 3_ based on my edit...

Comment: @CoolGuy Whoops, missed a critical one..thanks for bringing it to my attention, will updated. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As for determining whether or not a letter/char exists in the word you can use [strchr() function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_strchr.htm):

```
if(strchr (word,firstGuess)){
    printf("Correct Guess!!");
    flag_guess_correct = 1;     //flag is set when the guessed character is present in word
}
```